How to expose a custom field type's values in JSON:API & Openapi?
In a custom module, I extended Core's Entity Reference field type in order to allow for a custom link text.
/**
 * Plugin implementation of the 'Labelled Entity Reference' field type.
 *
 * @FieldType(
 *   id = "labelled_entity_reference",
 *   label = @Translation("Labelled Entity Reference"),
 *   description = @Translation("An entity field containing an entity reference with a label."),
 *   category = @Translation("Reference"),
 *   default_widget = "labelled_entity_reference_autocomplete",
 *   default_formatter = "labelled_entity_reference_view",
 *   list_class = "\Drupal\Core\Field\EntityReferenceFieldItemList",
 * )
 */
 
 class LabelledEntityReference extends EntityReferenceItem {
 
   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public static function propertyDefinitions(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition): array {
     $properties = parent::propertyDefinitions($field_definition);
     $properties['link_text'] = DataDefinition::create('string')
       ->setLabel(new TranslatableMarkup('Link Text'));
     return $properties;
   }
 
   /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
   public static function schema(FieldStorageDefinitionInterface $field_definition): array {
     $schema = parent::schema($field_definition);
     $schema['columns']['link_text'] = [
       'type' => 'var_char',
       'length' => 255,
       'description' => 'Optional link text for the entity reference link. If no link text is provided, the entity label will be used.',
     ];
 
     return $schema;
   }
 
 }

Field is working fine, I can save a value in link_text and use it for display. It is also exposed in JSON:API, however, it's "buried" in meta:
  "relationships": {
    "ref_label": {
      "data": {
        "type": "node--page",
        "id": "ece599fa-5526-4afe-a531-ca3224c79ce7",
        "meta": {
          "link_text": "My custom link text for the reference",
          "drupal__target_id": 1234
        }
      }

And the frontend system can't automatically get the link_text value, as it is not properly described via Openapi:
          "properties": {
            "ref_label": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "data": {
                  "type": "object",
                  "required": [
                    "type",
                    "id"
                  ],
                  "properties": {
                    "type": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "enum": [
                        "node--page"
                      ]
                    },
                    "id": {
                      "type": "string",
                      "format": "uuid",
                      "maxLength": 128
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }

I would expect that link_text is next to id and type inside the last properties or - according to JSON:API output - inside a meta object.
What am I missing so that JSON:API and Openapi properly pick up the extra field for my custom FieldType?
